# Properly set affine matrix and draw it in SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, matrix, graphics, skiasharp

I am trying to scale and skew a bitmap in SkiaSharp with an affine matrix, however; the results always cut part of the resulting bitmap. I am also not sure if my affine matrix has the correct values.

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to accomplish: on the left is the original image. It has a bitmap size of (178x242). On the right is the scaled and skewed image. The bounding box is (273x366), I also know that the the x scale has been skewed -10 pixels and the y scale has been skewed 7 pixels.

[image]

Here if my code for applying the affine matrix:

```
public SKBitmap ApplyAffine(SKBitmap origBitmap, SKSizeI newSize, SKPointI xyRotation)
{
     var skewX = 1f / xyRotation.X;
     var skewY = 1f / xyRotation.Y;

     // Scale transform
     var scaleX = (newSize.Width / (float)origBitmap.Width);
     var scaleY = (newSize.Height / (float)origBitmap.Height);

     // Affine transform
     SKMatrix affine = new SKMatrix
     {
         ScaleX = scaleX,
         SkewY = skewY,
         SkewX = skewX,
         ScaleY = scaleY,
         TransX = 0,
         TransY = 0,
         Persp2 = 1
     };

     var bitmap = origBitmap.Copy();
     var newBitmap = new SKBitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);

     using (var canvas = new SKCanvas(newBitmap))
     {
          canvas.SetMatrix(affine);
          canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0);
          canvas.Restore();
     }
     return newBitmap;
}
```

The resulting bitmap has the left side cut off. It also appears that it is not translated correctly. How do I properly apply this affine?

Comment: could you confirm the xyRotation contains (-10,7)?

Comment: Yes the xy rotation is (-10,7).

Comment: does the fixed answer fulfill what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right and the xyRotation is what I think it is from your description, then I think you were pretty close to the solution :)

```
public SKBitmap ApplyAffine(SKBitmap origBitmap, SKSizeI newSize, SKPointI xyRotation)
{
    // mcoo: skew is the tangent of the skew angle, but since xyRotation is not normalized
    // then it should be calculated based on original width/height
    var skewX = (float)xyRotation.X / origBitmap.Height;
    var skewY = (float)xyRotation.Y / origBitmap.Width;
    
    // Scale transform
    // mcoo (edit): we need to account here for the fact, that given skew is known AFTER the scale is applied
    var scaleX = (float)(newSize.Width - Math.Abs(xyRotation.X)) / origBitmap.Width;
    var scaleY = (float)(newSize.Height - Math.Abs(xyRotation.Y)) / origBitmap.Height;
    
    // Affine transform
    SKMatrix affine = new SKMatrix
    {
        ScaleX = scaleX,
        SkewY = skewY,
        SkewX = skewX,
        ScaleY = scaleY,
        //mcoo: we need to account for negative skew moving image bounds towards negative coords
        TransX = Math.Max(0, -xyRotation.X),
        TransY = Math.Max(0, -xyRotation.Y),
        Persp2 = 1
    };

    var bitmap = origBitmap.Copy();
    var newBitmap = new SKBitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);

    using (var canvas = new SKCanvas(newBitmap))
    {
        // canvas.Clear(SKColors.Red);
        canvas.SetMatrix(affine);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0);
    }
    return newBitmap;
}
```

Now calling `ApplyAffine(skBitmap, new SKSizeI(273, 366), new SKPointI(-10,7))` on image of size 178x242 yields somewhat correct result (red background added for reference):

[image]

Comment: Your solution is close, closer than mine is; but it is still just a little off. use this code to save the resulting bitmap: 
```string filename = "<your_filename>"; ```
```SKData d = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap).Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 100);    ```
```using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))```     
```d.SaveTo(fs);``` you will see that the right side and bottom have some white space. So the image does not fill it up completely

Comment: silly mistake by me, based  on  your drawing, the xyRotation contains shear values AFTER scaling is applied. So to calculate actual scale we need to go with `(float)(newSize.Width - Math.Abs(xyRotation.X)) / origBitmap.Width` rather than `newSize.Height / (float)(origBitmap.Height + Math.Abs(xyRotation.Y))`

Comment: I think that looks right on! Thanks, Just another small typo->the skewX is associated with Height and skewY is associated with Width. So just flip flopped. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For some reason SkiaSharp cuts off two pixels on the bottom left side. Not sure if that is a bug or what. I will have to test with other images

Comment: @tval skew is a tangent of shear angle, it was intentional to associate skewX with Height and skewY with Width. If you flip this association, positioning will be more off the larger values in xyRotation are.

Comment: @tval regarding the cut off, if you swapped the width and height for skew calculation then this might be the reason :) Try changing X in xyRotation to e.g. -100 and you'll see why the way I did it was intentional